# Is there a way to know if Vimeo video was watched by current browser user?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

We are showing several Vimeo videos on a page. We want to show watched videos differently (like you see it on youtube - watched label and video is a bit transparent).

A perfect thing for us would be a JSONP method that you can specify an array of video IDs and it returns a list of flags says which videos were watched by current user.

Better if this can be a non API method (so that this request can be made directly from user's browser with his Vimeo cookies to Vimeo server).

In Vimeo API I could find only how to get all videos watched by me https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/me#/watched/videos.

**UPD** also posted on Vimeo forums https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:278934

**UPD 2** I've checked on youtube: if you are not logged in and you watch a video - it does not appear as "watched" afterwards. So probably this question is not relevant because our users are also mostly not logged into vimeo.

Comment: Questions with links are pretty useless really as those of us who are pros often cant go to the sites you've linked, and in the future when they've changed nobody will be able to go to them. Please put a summary in the question itself. Read [ask]

Comment: You can read summary in question title or a longer version in description. I don't understand what is wrong sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is: "You don't want it actually".

Because our users are not forced to be logged in to vimeo. This means that vimeo has no place where to store this information (that certain videos were watched).